# Enforcing spaces in string resources

Tags: android, string

In an Android string resource, how do I enforce a space?

For example, when I do " result" rather than "result" I still see "result" in my application's text view.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Did you try to surround your string with quotes? Maybe leading and trailing whitespaces are stripped automatically.

```
<string name="foo">" bar"</string>
```

See the example at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling in section *"Escaping apostrophes and quotes"*.

Comment: Awesome! I did not know we could achieve that with double quotes on `strings.xml`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 101):

As an alternative to the answer given by Andreas Klöber you can use this method:

```
<string name="foobar">foo \u0020 bar</string>
```

This utilizes the unicode space character (\u0020).

Comment: What about &#160; delimeter?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky They are interchangeable, like in most languages.

Answer (score -8):

Just quote the value, like this

```
<string name="str_name">" Hello World!"</string>
```

Comment: This approach would require developer to manually count the number of spaces by hand, if they care about this number.

Comment: Subtract four spaces and it would be identical to the accepted answer.