# Escaping whitespace Android strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enforcing spaces in string resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624755/enforcing-spaces-in-string-resources)

This is the strings.xml file I use for my Android project.

```xml
........
........
<string name="bcount">Block Count\t\t\t: </string>
<string name="fbcount">Free Blocks\t\t\t: </string>
<string name="blsiz">Block Size\t\t\t: </string>
<string name="newvfs">New VFS</string>
<string name="mknewfold">Making new folder </string>
<string name="creating">Creating </string>
........
........
```

The problem with this is that whitespaces towards end of strings like `"Block Count\t\t\t: "`disappear. Only `"Block Count\t\t\t:"`is returned by java. How to fix this?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Good find. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android doesn't support keeping the spaces at the end, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/android-string-concatenate-how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-beginnin) Stackoverflow Answer for more information.

The solution-slash-workaround is to use \u0020 in stead of those suffix spaces.